# When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?

Tags: c#, .net, settings

When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?
I want to delete the saved settings to go back to the default state, but can't find where it's stored... any ideas?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It depends on whether the setting you have chosen is at "User" scope or "Application" scope.

#### User scope

User scope settings are stored in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ username \Local Settings\Application Data\ ApplicationName
```

You can read/write them at runtime.

For Vista and Windows 7, folder is

```
C:\Users\ username \AppData\Local\ ApplicationName
```

or

```
C:\Users\ username \AppData\Roaming\ ApplicationName
```

#### Application scope

Application scope settings are saved in `AppName.exe.config` and they are readonly at runtime.

Comment: The folder for user scope settings on Vista and Win7 is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ApplicationName\Publisher\ApplicationName\Version
or
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\Publisher\ApplicationName\Version
depending on the Roaming property value on Settings pane.

Comment: unless its an addin, in which case it will be AppName.dll.config

Comment: My local user.config on Windows 7 is in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Publisher\ApplicationName_Eid_EvidenceHash\Version

Answer (score 56):

Here is the snippet you can use to programmatically get user.config file location:

```
public static string GetDefaultExeConfigPath(ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel)
{
  try
  {
    var UserConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(userLevel);
    return UserConfig.FilePath;
  }
  catch (ConfigurationException e)
  {
    return e.Filename;
  }
}
```

ApplicationSettings (i.e. settings.settings) use PerUserRoamingAndLocal for user settings by default (as I remembered).

**Update:** Strange but there are too many incorrect answers here. If you are looking for you user scoped settings file (user.config) it will be located in the following folder (for Windows XP):

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\(username)\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\(company-name-if-exists)\(app-name).exe_(Url|StrongName)_(hash)\(app-version)\

Url or StrongName depends on have you application assembly strong name or not.

Comment: Any idea what contributes to the hash in that path? Each subsequent release of my app is getting a different hash value, which makes calling ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade() futile. :/

Comment: Hash is SHA1 hash of StrongName when app is signed or path when app is unsigned. More here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that you're talking about desktop and not web applications:

When you add settings to a project, VS creates a file named `app.config` in your project directory and stores the settings in that file.  It also builds the `Settings.cs` file that provides the static accessors to the individual settings.

At compile time, VS will (by default; you can change this) copy the `app.config` to the build directory, changing its name to match the executable (e.g. if your executable is named `foo.exe`, the file will be named `foo.exe.config`), which is the name the .NET configuration manager looks for when it retrieves settings at runtime.

If you change a setting through the VS settings editor, it will update both `app.config` and `Settings.cs`.  (If you look at the property accessors in the generated code in `Settings.cs`, you'll see that they're marked with an attribute containing the default value of the setting that's in your `app.config` file.)  If you change a setting by editing the `app.config` file directly, `Settings.cs` won't be updated, but the new value will still be used by your program when you run it, because `app.config` gets copied to `foo.exe.config` at compile time.  If you turn this off (by setting the file's properties), you can change a setting by directly editing the `foo.exe.config` file in the build directory.

Then there are user-scoped settings.

Application-scope settings are read-only.  Your program can modify and save user-scope settings, thus allowing each user to have his/her own settings.  These settings aren't stored in the `foo.exe.config` file (since under Vista, at least, programs can't write to any subdirectory of `Program Files` without elevation); they're stored in a configuration file in the user's application data directory.

The path to that file is `%appdata%\%publisher_name%\%program_name%\%version%\user.config`, e.g. `C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\My_Company\My_Program.exe\1.0.0\user.config`.  Note that if you've given your program a strong name, the strong name will be appended to the program name in this path.

Comment: It looks like the My_Company component of the path will default to Microsoft.  I've not yet found a way to change this that actually works, if someone knows that would be good to add.

Comment: user565869,  have you tried  in visual studio, open the project property's application  tab, click the assembly information button and you should then be able to change Company? repeat that for each project in your solution

Answer (score 16):

While browsing around to figure out about the hash in the folder name, I came across (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1928041/745913)):

<del>http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx</del>

(edit: Wayback Machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160307233557/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx)

> The exact path of the `user.config` files looks something like this:
>
> `<Profile Directory>\<Company Name>\<App Name>_<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>\<Version>\user.config`
>
> where
>
> `<Profile Directory>` - is either the roaming profile directory or the local one. Settings are stored by default in the local `user.config` file. To store a setting in the roaming `user.config` file, you need to mark the setting with the `SettingsManageabilityAttribute` with `SettingsManageability` set to `Roaming`.
>
> `<Company Name>` - is typically the string specified by the `AssemblyCompanyAttribute` (with the caveat that the string is escaped and truncated as necessary, and if not specified on the assembly, we have a fallback procedure).
>
> `<App Name>` - is typically the string specified by the `AssemblyProductAttribute` (same caveats as for company name).
>
> `<Evidence Type>` and `<Evidence Hash>` - information derived from the app domain evidence to provide proper app domain and assembly isolation.
>
> `<Version>` - typically the version specified in the `AssemblyVersionAttribute`. This is required to isolate different versions of the app deployed side by side.
>
> The file name is always simply '`user.config`'.

Comment: Unfortunately the blog link is broken. I'm sure it would have been interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It is in a folder with your application's name in Application Data folder in User's home folder (C:\documents and settings\user on xp and c:\users\user on Windows Vista).

There is some information [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t481744.html) also.

PS:- try accessing it by %appdata% in run box!

Answer (score 3):

Erm, can you not just use Settings.Default.Reset() to restore your default settings?

Answer (score 2):

If your settings file is in a web app, they will be in teh web.config file (right below your project.  If they are in any other type of project, they will be in the app.config file (also below your project).

**Edit**

As is pointed out in the comments:  your design time application settings are in an app.config file for applications other than web applications.  When you build, the app.config file is copied to the output directory, and will be named *yourexename*.exe.config.  At runtime, only the file named yourexename.exe.config will be read.

Comment: Not correct. There is no app.config settings file in running application, because app.config will be renamed into [appname].exe.config. And anyway this file will contain only ApplicationScoped settings from settings.settins.

Comment: @arbiter:
Perhaps I missunderstood the question, but Adam appeared to be asking about the design-time defaults.  Those are stored in app.config.  At build-time, teh app.config file is copied to the build directory and renamed to (theapp.exe.config).  However, if you edit that file directly (and are working in visual studio), you run the risk of the contents being overwritten the next time you build.  
Bottom line:  For a deployed app (or if you are running outside the IDE), change teh name.exe.config file).  If you are working in VS, change either the default value in settings, or app.config

Answer (score 1):

All your settings are stored in the respective .config file.

The .settings file simply provides a strongly typed class for a set of settings that belong together, but the actual settings are stored in app.config or a .config file in your application.

If you add a .settings file, an app.config will be automatically added to house the settings if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Two files:
1) An app.config or web.config file.  The settings her can be customized after build with a text editer.
2) The settings.designer.cs file.  This file has autogenerated code to load the setting from the config file, but a default value is also present in case the config file does not have the particular setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already answered but couldn't you just synchronize the settings in the settings designer to move back to your default settings?