# Saving properties in Settings.settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, properties, settings

I'm trying to save some data at the runtime:

```
SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty("tabSetting");
property.Name = "tab";
property.PropertyType=typeof(string);
property.DefaultValue = "path";
Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Settings.Default.Save();
```

but this code don't save any changes in file Settings.settings.

Also I try to make changes in Settings.settings from VisualStudio, I open this file and write settings by hand. After that I run the code which is mentioned above and get this exeption:

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'tab'  Key being added: 'tab'
```

Why  `Settings.Default.Save()` code is not working?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if your settings are user, or application in scope. It makes a difference in where your settings file is saved. Is sounds as if your settings are **User** scope and you are looking for them in the application settings file. The exception is a clue the setting already exists. Look at this question / answer for more information. [When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075204/when-using-a-settings-settings-file-in-net-where-is-the-config-actually-stored)