# How to get the folder of current Applicationsettings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, settings

I read the post:
[When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075204/when-using-a-settings-settings-file-in-net-where-is-the-config-actually-stored)
When I searched for the settings of my Application, there was a slightly different structure then discirped by the post mentioned above, here are a few names of subdirectorys below the folder with the companys name:

```
Tool.exe_Url_bnnjvtuwgh3w2wbjgypnx0dubiiom0r4
Tool.exe_Url_nasn1gkpw40gbo1atjv3bqoaa2gt40ks     
Tool.exe_StrongName_jsnxyxauq3wdhij1csysoqdas1jdi3pl   
Tool2.exe_Url_4xylmurehvveuiwvvvgkuixndayhv3sk
```

under these dirctory's are directory's for the actual Versions located, some versions are even in multiple directory's. And in this Version directory's are finally my Settings

How is the ending with the numbers and letters produced? Or let me get closer to my actual issue: How can I determine at runtime which name the folder, in which my settings will be, actual has or will have as soon as I first create a Settingsfile by calling `Settings.save()`?