# When I've deployed a Windows Forms application, how can I change the default settings?

Tags: winforms, deployment, configuration-files

I've deployed a Windows Forms application. On my local development PC, there is a `settings.settings` file which contains all the app's settings.

I'm aware as-per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075204/when-using-a-settings-settings-file-in-net-where-is-the-config-actually-stored) and others like it, that a User.config file gets created in `c:\Users\username\Local Settings\AppData\Local\...`

However, I need to change a default setting, so that when users start it for the first time, the default settings are different than when we initially deployed the app.

So the first time a user runs the app, it creates their local copy of the file.

What does it base that on? Is there a default copy of the file somewhere, or is it compiled into the .exe?

I need to get the default settings updated on an app that's deployed on several laptops remotely where I only have telephone support. If I have to recompile and republish then that needs to be as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this facts may be useful:

- The default values for user settings are stored in `yourapplication.exe.config` beside `yourapplication.exe`
- Current values for user settings are not in this file and any change in them could be saved using `Properties.Default.Settings.Save()`
- If there is no `yourapplication.exe.config` in your executable folder, it will be created automatically using values in your `.settings` file.
- If you call `Properties.Default.Settings.Reset()` the values in `yourapplication.exe.config` will be used to override user saved values.
- Adding a new settings requires recompile and republish.
- To overcome the pain of update and distribution, you may consider ClickOnce.