# Automatically "upgrade" user settings from previous version of app.config file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config, application-settings

Every time I compile my app and the version number changes (I have an auto-incrementing build number), I lose the user-configured app.config settings, since they're stored in the AppData folder for a specific version. Essentially, every release of my application starts from scratch as far as user settings go.

While this is a mild annoyance in development, it raises the question as I approach deployment/release - **if I use the app.config to store my user settings, will the user's personalized settings be hosed every time they install a patch that changes the version number of my app?** If so, is there an easy way to "upgrade" the settings from the previous release? I know that using HKCU in the registry is another option, but I like the ease of the My.Settings namespace, and I'd like to stay with app.config.

[Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621265/net-2-0-application-settings-user-config-file-location) asks something similar, though the answer doesn't seem that clear. Will setting my MSI so it asks the user to upgrade be enough to preserve these user-level settings?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you looked at [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx)? It allows the settings to be upgraded from a previous version using the following call:

```
My.Settings.Upgrade()
```

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I was looking for - it fetches the most recent copy of the settings and loads those. Also worth noting is the ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPreviousVersion method, which you can use to load a single setting from a previous version. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why but neither the upgrade command or the get previous version seems to work for me. What could I be doing wrong? Do I need to call a refresh command or something. I am doing this on form load, should it be an application event?

*UPDATE*

Found out why, it seems it does not work when you use a 4 digit major version number. I was using the year 2012 as the major version number. I have changed that to 12 and it works like a charm, though is no not millenium compliant. Still I got 88 years before I need to start worrying about that!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered ClickOnce deployment? This topic is then covered [in depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228995.aspx). IMO, ClickOnce is much easier both for the developer and the user.

Comment: ClickOnce is great until it doesn't work, and then debugging it is nearly impossible.  We used to use it, and replaced it with a "launcher" type program of our own because there were too many things which could go wrong out of our control and without sufficient logging which left the user sol.