# How to save to external config file

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

In ABC.exe.config (app.config)

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="MySettings.config">
        <add key="setting1" value="1" />
    </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

Here I use "file" attribute, not "configSource", because I want to define default values.
How to save to external config file "MySettings.config"?
I must keep "ABC.exe.config" unchanged because it will be overwritten on program upgrade without notice. All global settings must be preserved in "MySettings.config"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically "upgrade" user settings from previous version of app.config file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198193/automatically-upgrade-user-settings-from-previous-version-of-app-config-file)

Comment: No! This is not the duplicate. I do not use the upgrade method, which stores settings in User account (local). I need to save global settings which stores in the exe folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example in the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.file.aspx) , the approach is to handle the write to the file yourself, i.e. treat it as a "regular" XML file for example.