# save settings after update VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to know if it was possible to keep user settings after an upgrade, I'll explain: I've My.Settings in some default values, then the user is using some functions can change the values. I have noticed that if you download the latest version that I release loses all settings will return because the default ones ... this is bad even for my protection system, is there any function that allows me to maintain the user settings when upgrading to the new .exe? what code should I implement? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [Automatically “upgrade” user settings from previous version of app.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198193/automatically-upgrade-user-settings-from-previous-version-of-app-config-file)?

Comment: ...or [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I then just plug this method in order to update automatically? thanks for the support.