# My Configuration file is not updated

Tags: c#

Im using  Properties.Setting file to save some data. And using my program im going to update it as follows.
Settings.Default.test = "new Value";
            Settings.Default.Save();
But its not updated in my app.config file.

Im using VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set one or more of the settings to be `User` settings? If so, they should be updated when you save, but remember that they won't be written into the app.config file, rather, they'll be written to the user.config file instead (since the app.config file is likely to be located in a directory to which you won't have write permissions).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621265/net-2-0-application-settings-user-config-file-location) discusses where the user.config file will be stored.