# Remove the version number from file path

Tags: c#, properties, settings

I save the user settings with Properties.Settings.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.key = "value";
Properties.Settings.Default.save();
```

and here is the saved file:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Me\MyCompany\0.0.1\user.config
```

How can I prevent that the version number is in the path, like that?

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Me\MyCompany\user.config
```

Comment: You could write your own settings provider. Some information here: http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/dotnet2customsettingsprovider.htm

Comment: The <version> number is the AssemblyInfo's AssemblyVersionAttribute setting. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/621295/495455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found another way.

After starting the program I let run the following code:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired= false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

`UpgradeRequired` is a user-specific property, the default value is true

Comment: It's not exactly that what I looking for, but it fixes the problem ;)