# application settings file complexity in C#

Tags: c#, application-settings

I added a **settings file** in my service application developed by **C# in VS2008**. In the designer of settings file, i inserted new datetime variable with `user scope` and entered default value for that datetime variable. For instance, suppose that the name of this variable is `MyDate` and its value is "`2013-01-08`". 
When i run my service application, i get the value of `MyDate` correctly with the following code line:

```
Datetime value = app.Default.MyDate; // app is the name of the settings file
```

After that i set `MyDate` to "`2013-01-08 14:00:00`" with the following line of code:

```
app.Default.MyDate = DateTime.Now; // Suppose Now is 2013-01-08 14:00:00 at that time.
app.Default.Save();
```

Everything is OK until now. `MyDate` parameter is set to what i want. However, i can not see the new value in `app.config` file. When i open the config file in Debug folder, i only see that:

```
    <setting name="MyDate" serializeAs="String">
        <value>2013-01-08</value>
    </setting>
```

And surprisingly, When i rerun the application, `MyDate` parameter is seem to be "`2013-01-08 14:00:00`" insead of "`2013-01-08`"! I looked every config file in Debug folder and project folder but i couldn't find any value with "`2013-01-08 14:00:00`". But `MyDate` parameter is set to this value on startup. 
I want to know where the value of MyDate variable is stored? Which file should i look for?


**SOLUTION EDIT:** I decided not to use settings file. I will use app.config file insead of settings file inorder to store my application parameters. app.config is not type-safe but it is easier to edit parameters infile. On the other hand, settings file is like a closed box that you can not find the file which it stores the parameter values.

Comment: Are you trying to write the value to the config file?

Comment: @BrettAllred i want to be able to edit the value of the variable manually too in config file. But When i changed the config file, it doesnt affect the variable value. Whatismore, i can not find the current value of the variable in any config file.

Answer (score 1):

That's because they are stored in the

`<Profile Directory>\<Company Name>\<App Name>_<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>\<Version>\user.config` file.

For example: `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\<Company>\<Product>\<Version>\user.config` file.

From your code, you may use:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

to get the storage location for your local application data.

**[UPDATE]**

As you mentioned it is a Windows Service application, try searching the following path:

`c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\`

Comment: i couldn't find C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\<Company>\<Product>\<Version>\user.config file path. I looked at Document and Settings folder "Local Setting/Application Data" but there is no file with my application's name.

Comment: Can you see the company name from your project when you go to: `%APPDATA%`?

Comment: My company name of my service application is empty. [assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]. So i can not see my company name at %APPDATA% folder. What should i do to see the file?

Comment: Just ignore the `<Company>` part of the path, use `<Profile Directory>\<App Name>_<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>\<Version>\user.config` (i.e. `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\<Product>\<Version>\user.config`)

Comment: It is not there either. i started file search. Windows is searching for user.config files. By the way, why doesnt this value be stored in myapplication.exe.config file?

Comment: @Edwin de Koning Windows couldn't find any user.config file. My application is a windows service application. Is that why there is no user.config file for that application?

Comment: i have already tried that. There are no folder named "Local" in "systemprofile\AppData" folder. There is "Local Settings" folder and i looked that folder too. But there is not any file related to my service application. Althought i found that configuration file which i need, i have to look for a complex path everytime i need to check that file. So i think i should consider using App.config file insead of App.Settings file. Settings file is headache when you want to edit it manually with notepad.

Answer (score 1):

The settings with user scope are not actually stored in your app.config, but in a file named `user.config`. The location of this file is determined by the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` property. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more details on the architecture.

You can also change this location if you want to, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621265/can-i-control-the-location-of-net-user-settings-to-avoid-losing-settings-on-app) for more details.

Comment: How can i get this file path. I dont use System.Windows.Form because my application is a service application.

Comment: @Fer Hmmm.. How about c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ ?

Comment: it is not there neither. I started a file search of "user.config". It seems it will take long time. By the way, why doesnt this value be stored in myapplication.exe.config file?

Comment: @Fer The value in your in exe.config is essentially a default value, in case your settings file should go missing.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is OK until now. MyDate parameter is set to what i want.
>   However, i can not see the new value in app.config file.

Here you are doing a misunderstanding with App.config file. the app.config file is your solution file which is a part of your coding / design time. this should not be changed when you run your application either in debug mode or in release mode. what exactly happening is. this one having your default settings. for your App.

say you run your application in debug mode and this will generate output into Bin/ Debug folder which should be having myapplication.exe.config. you need to see this file instead of app.config. what so ever you changed are get changed into myapplication.exe.config. file not in app.config.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but note that i tried editing myapplication.exe.config file too and it doesnt change the value of my variable neither.