# c#: How to save assembly settings?

Tags: c#, config, .net-assembly

I have unmanaged C++ application which uses c# assembly. I want to save/read assembly settings. I added mySettigs to assembly and read/save settings to config file.

I have found this file

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\MayCrossoft\DefaultDomain_Path_l5epjb2agsxbnfr1mif5euhhtr3x5ed3\1.1.0\user.config
```

The question is: what need to do to change "DefaultDomain_Path_" to assembly name ?

Thnx.

Comment: Does this user.config have anything to do with your unmanaged application or is it just some file you found?  Unmanaged c++ applications don't normally use app.config or user.config...

Comment: You might want to check out Amr's answer to a similar question here: [Can I control the location of .NET user settings...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621265/can-i-control-the-location-of-net-user-settings-to-avoid-losing-settings-on-app)

Comment: 2 Peter: This file user.config used only by managed assembly. The way is: unmanaged c++ code->managed c++ code->c# assembly. I need this user.config for this c# assembly only.

Comment: 2 RogerN: Thank you for the link. But I cannot find Upgrade method in my settings. I have added them via Add new.