# My application Settings get reset after changing product version

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have created an application using Settings from Project Properties. This setting has been used to store some boolean and string variables. I know the settings are user base. So, it can be stored separately for each windows user. I have also added a feature to update application from web server. But, recently i have notice that when i have change the product version then all the settings are get reset. It should not be. How to avoid resetting all setting on version change.

**This question is not for only c#. this problem also occurred in vb.**

Comment: that is because the app name/version is part of the hash used for the settings storage location. Lots more info here in [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/621265/1070452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Settings.Upgrade()` or `ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPreviousVersion`

Note: You must call only once this method.

[Client Settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx)