# User.config environment variables

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have a client who is running my program on a server and is having an issue with user.config file, they claim that everyone is using the same config file but I thought it was stored on each individual computer.  Could someone tell me the exact environment variables that Microsoft uses to create the config file.  I've read mixed messages on this.

Comment: You can get config setting from cmd.exe >Set,  You can put the output into a file using >Set > environ.txt  Then get samples of from different account to see the differences.

Comment: Depends.  Worth checking these threads out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621265/can-i-control-the-location-of-net-user-settings-to-avoid-losing-settings-on-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it.  I would assume its the app.config file you have settings in?

Comment: Environment variables play no role whatsoever.  Consider that everybody is running it remotely, executing the program on the server instead of their own machine.  And using something like Remote Desktop to connect to the server.

Comment: The above thread says %appdata% but my %appdata% is "c:\computername\appdata\roaming" but the actual file is under local not roaming.  That is what I meant  by mixed messages.  I was hoping to find out what Microsoft uses for for the location of the user.config file.  If a program is run on a server where should the user.config file reside?