# User settings on .NET

Tags: .net, settings

I'm having some weird trouble with a project on VS2005.

I have a few user settings configured, but every time i start the project (on release mode) it comes with a previously tested configuration.

I've tried synching it many times, but i cannot succeed. Most of these properties are empty strings by default. I have a installer class and project also, but i'm not sure if these are affecting this behavior (i'm clicking only in the other project i want to debug)

Any thoughts?

EDIT

i already deleted these

[Where are user-mode .NET settings stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469742/where-are-user-mode-net-settings-stored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the app.config file in the project.  I have seen it where multiple Settings sections get defined (especially if you have ever renamed your project).

Try getting rid of any superfluous Settings sections (don't forget to remove the section element from the configSections tag as well.)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
       <section name="ProjectName.Properties.Settings" />
       <!-- Remove this -->
       <section name="OldProjectName.Properties.Settings" />
     </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
     <ProjectName.Properties.Settings>
        <!-- Project Settings Appear here -->
     </ProjectName.Properties.Settings>
     <!-- Remove this -->
     <OldProjectName.Properties.Settings>
        <!-- Old Project Settings Appear here -->
     </OldProjectName.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the document contains really just one set of settings. :/