# How to get my app settings folder path for the current user?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I use the code

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

to save my settings it writes the file to this path

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MyAppName\MyAppName.exe_Url_SomeWeirdCode\TheAppVersionNumber\user.config
```

For example

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\MyApp\MyApp.exe_Url_claumreyuxtgqul2vuc3couyu5tso2n0\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

How can I get the path to the app version folder (1.0.0.0) so I can write other stuff to it?

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.2 and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/982354/1688738.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the file path like this:

```
var level = ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal;
var configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(level);
var configurationFilePath = configuration.FilePath
```

To make this work, you need to add reference to `System.Configuration.dll` (right-click your WPF project, select **Add**, **Reference...** and check the box next to `System.Configuration` in the **Assemblies/Framework** page.

Comment: it gets me the path for the config file itself not the folder but i can work with that,
thanks

Answer (score -2):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

This returns a string that goes to AppData.
Just add the rest of your file path on to the end of it.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like *"Just add the rest of your file path on to the end of it"* is a pretty vague replacement for correctly adding something similar to `MyApp\MyApp.exe_Url_claumreyuxtgqul2vuc3couyu5tso2n0\1.0.0.0` and possibly maintaining it accross multiple version updates.

Comment: the problem is the code after the appname.exe "claumreyuxtgqul2vuc3couyu5tso2n0" is unique for each user and or pc i can't just put an static value for it

Comment: Oh I think I understand now, your trying to find a file which exists with an identifier that's unique.

Comment: @JacksonTarisa yes